# Do you add your ability modifier to damage for the Soulknife's second attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, rogue, two-weapon-fighting

Normal Two-Weapon Fighting lets you use your bonus action when you've used your action to *attack*. It says:

> You don't add your ability modifier to the damage of the bonus attack, unless that modifier is negative.

The new *Tasha's Cauldron* subclass *Soulknife* has a feature where you can create a blade of energy and attack with it, and that says:

> After you attack with the blade, you can make a melee or ranged weapon attack with a second psychic blade as a bonus action on the same turn, provided your other hand is free to create it. The damage die of this bonus attack is 1d4, instead of 1d6.

It looks to me that, while this is *similar* to Two-Weapon Fighting, it is not that same, and the normal bonus to damage would apply. Am I right?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

#### Not adding the modifier is a special feature of Two-Weapon Fighting.

The [rules for damage](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#DamageRolls) say:

> When attacking with a weapon, you add your ability modifier — the same modifier used for the attack roll — to the damage.

*Notice there is no mention of this being an attack action or attack with a bonus action.* This is the **general** rule for making an attack.

In contrast, [Two-Weapon Fighting](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#TwoWeaponFighting) has a **specific** rule:

> You don't add your ability modifier to the damage of the bonus attack, unless that modifier is negative.

This rule is **specific** to Two-Weapon Fighting - it creates an exception to the general rule for damage rolls.<sup>1</sup>

So you add your modifier to the damage of Soul knife’s bonus action attack since nothing in the ability contradicts the **general** rule of adding your ability modifier to the damage.

---

<sup>1 The game has a ["specific beats general"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/introduction#SpecificBeatsGeneral) rule in the introduction to the *Player's Handbook* which states: "That said, many racial traits, class features, spells, magic items, monster abilities, and other game elements break the general rules in some way, creating an exception to how the rest of the game works. Remember this: If a specific rule contradicts a general rule, the specific rule wins."</sup>

Comment: I like this answer because it also highlights that the reason TWF doesn't get it is because specific overrides general.

Comment: Thanks for confirming!

Comment: @mattdm Note that the same logic applies to other TWF-like sources of a secondary attack, such as the Polearm Master feat or the double-bladed scimitar in Eberron.

Comment: Nice answer. It might be worth pointing out why the specific rules of TWF *don't* apply to the Soulknife's second attack. Someone could easily assume they could: after all, it does specify that you must use your "other hand" to create a blade for the bonus-action attack. However, it definitely isn't TWF for two reasons: the Psychic Blades aren't light, and you aren't already holding both blades when you start the attack.