# How is the Soul Knife Rogue's Bonus action attack affected by a multiclass with Monk?

Tags: dnd-5e, monk, multi-classing, rogue

The Soul Knife Rogue has a feature called *Psychic Blades*, which includes this ability:

> After you attack with the blade, you can make a melee or ranged weapon attack with a second psychic blade as a bonus action on the same turn, provided your other hand is free to create it. The damage die of this bonus attack is 1d4, instead of 1d6.

As is, the *psychic blade* is a simple melee weapon and as such qualifies as a monk weapon.

I think its fairly obvious that the original 1d6 of the blade will increase as a monk weapon would normally do, but does the bonus action damage also increase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The damage die of a psychic blade could increase at DM's discretion.

As you mentioned, the psychic blade fully qualifies as a monk special weapon and could benefit from *martial arts* and other monk features that require a monk weapon.

The damage die of the second attack could be modified by Martial Arts at DM's discretion following the rule Specific Beats General:

> If a specific rule contradicts a general rule, the specific rule wins.

Both *Martial Arts* and *Psychic Blades* present some specific rules.

I wouldd (personally) rule that *Martial Arts* could also increase the damage die of this second attack, since the second psychic blade still is a simple melee weapon that is not heavy nor two-handed, and you also have to invest at least 5 levels in monk to increase its damage die, so it wouldn't break anything to allow it.

Other DMs might see the damage die reduction as a more specific rule, disallowing the second attack's damage die from being modified this way. This is also a fine way to rule it.

---

However, reading the feature RAW, you cannot create psychic blades more than once per Attack action, and you can create one as a bonus action only in specific circumstances.

> Whenever you take the Attack action, you can manifest **a** psychic blade from your free hand and make the attack with that blade. [...] The blade vanishes immediately after it hits or misses its target [...] After you attack with the blade, you can make a melee or ranged weapon attack with **a second** psychic blade as a bonus action on the same turn, *provided your other hand is free to create it*. [...]

The feature lets you create one psychic blade when you take the Attack action, not when you *attack as part of the Attack action*, so features like Extra Attack cannot use more than one psychic blade, and it has been established with [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/177885/why-is-soulknifes-second-attack-not-two-weapon-fighting) that this bonus action is not the same as using *Two-Weapon Fighting* (and *Martial Arts* by the same logic). The special bonus action of this feature allows you to do something similar to two-weapon fighting or using the bonus action attack of martial arts.

Comment: What makes Martial Arts a more specific feature in this case than the modification from Psychic Blades?

Comment: @DavidCoffron I made it more clear that both are specific, so it's up to the DM.